# WP_Editor - Saving Value into Plugin Option - Stripping HTML

Tags: plugin-development, options, wp-editor, sanitization, escaping

I have a `wp_editor();` on my plugin settings page.

I also have enabled the "Font Size" drop down in TinyMCE.

After highlighting text in the `wp_editor();` and selecting a font size from the editor's drop down menu, the font size is adjusted appropriately (directly in the editor).

However, after saving my plugin settings using `update_option();` and the plugin settings page reloads... The `<span style="font-size: 18px;">highlighted text</span>` is removed, leaving me with only "highlighted text" without span tags wrapping it to adjust the font size.

I tried investigating the `wp_editor();` code, along with the `add_option();` / `update_option();` code, to see if maybe there was some sort of stripping/sanitization going on.

Any clue why a `wp_editor();` span tag would be removed while saving it's contents to an option?

**Side note:** 
It seems like only the span tags are being stripped for some reason. I just tried using underline, and that was removed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

This turned out to be a common case of needing to use [`stripslashes();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

**How did I figure this out?**

I logged into phpMyAdmin, navigated to the options table, found my option name, and edited it.

**Here's what I discovered...**

`s:11:"description";s:90:"<span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">This is supposed to be underlined text.</span>";`

So obviously my plugin is working. It's saving stuff properly. The text I entered into the `wp_editor();` is there, and the appropriate HTML is wrapping my text as well.

Notice the slashes that have been added automatically. This is what was causing the problem when outputting the contents from the `wp_editor();` which were saved in my plugin option.

**Simple Solution**

1. Use `stripslashes();` after retrieving your option data before you
   output it.
2. This should be done on output and not on input.